# Как передать значение переменной из одного окна в другое Qt?

Tags: qt, qtcreator

Есть два окна MainWindow и Dialog. Нужно что бы при нажатии на кнопку открывалось диалоговое окно(Dialog) и из MainWindow в Dialog передавалось значение переменной "x" из MainWindow в label в Dialog.

// mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_Button_clicked()
{
    QString x = "hello";
    Dialog window;
    window.setModal(true);
    window.exec();
}
```

// dialog.cpp

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Объяви в `Dialog.h` член-функцию `void setLabel(const QString& x)` и определи в `Dialog.cpp` реализацию:

```
void Dialog::setLabel(const QString& x)
{
    ui->label->setText(x);
}
```

Потом после создания объекта класса `Dialog` вызывай `window.setLabel(x);`

Comment: ну да, или так, тоже правильно

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте конструктор Dialog со вторым аргументом

```
Dialog(QWidget *parent, QString labelText);
```

да и `window.setModal(true);` излишне его `QDialog::exec()` сам делает

Comment: Так и не понял как по нажатию на кнопку(Button) переменная "x" будет выведена в label диалогового окна(Dialog)